# Having trouble binding to Active Directory with specified credentials

Tags: powershell

As part of my current role, I frequently find myself having to work with objects in one of my organisation's resource forests. At the moment in order to do that, I use an RDP session connected to a server within that forest, and authenticate to it with a specific "Admin" account in that forest.

I'm starting to find this tedious, and so I've been trying to come up with a nice profile.ps1 which will get me a DirectoryEntry for the resource forest that I can work on with Powershell (v2.0) on my local workstation instead, and save me the tedium of constantly re-establishing RDP sessions.

So I've got some code in my profile.ps1 which looks like this:

```
$resforest = "LDAP://DC=ldap,DC=path,DC=details"
$creds = Get-Credential -credential "RESOURCE_FOREST\my_admin_account"
$username = $creds.username
$password = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().password

$directoryentry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($resforest,$username,$password)
```

All of this proceeds fine, however, when I come to actually use the entry thus:

```
$search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryentry)
$search.filter = "(&(anr=something_to_look_for))"
$search.findall()
```

I get a logon failure.

Now, I know the credentials are fine, I can map drives with them from my workstation to machines in the resource forest - and that works fine - so what am I ballsing up here?

PS - Please don't ask me to do anything with Quest's AD cmdlets - they're not allowed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the serverless binding I was attempting to do.

If I modify the LDAP path to "LDAP://ldap.path.details/DC=ldap,DC=path,DC=details" then everything works.

Thanks for everyone who at least looked at the question ;)